# send_file sending from IP of server, not domain

Tags: python, flask

I have a route in my flask application. But when it sends the file it shows it's coming from ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx instead of domain.com

here is my route

```
@app.route('/mp4/')
@db_session
def mp4():
    filename = request.args.get('filename')
    response = make_response(filename)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'video/mp4'
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
    response.headers['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)
    return send_file(
                 filename,
                 mimetype="video/mp4",
                 as_attachment=True,
                 attachment_filename="%s" % filename)
```

How do I make it so it shows sending from domain instead of the servers ip?

Comment: Tell us were you do see the IP address, instead of the domain name. I guess this is more of a DNS problem than flask related.

Comment: when I receive the file in the browser.